# java httpurlconnection fails with connection reset

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm starting coding in java and tried converting an existing .NET application that makes an httpwebrequest connection to a continuous stream of data. I tried the following code but the connection if still false and although it seems like it connects no data is retrieved and then it fails with connection reset.

```
private static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String urlString, String username, String password) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



    connection.setReadTimeout(300000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", createAuthHeader(username, password));
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("useragent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows 
           NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");


    return connection;
    }
    ...

    public Producer(Properties cprops, String kafkaBroker, String kafkaTopic) {
....
    try {

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String username = "me.com";
        String password = "password";
        String url = "https:/something.com.json";
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;


        try {

            connection = getConnection(url, username, password);
            connection.connect();
            inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            int numbytesRead = 0;

            if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299) {
            BufferedReader reader = 
                                   new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
                                  (new StreamingGZIPInputStream(inputStream), charset));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while(true){
                //read message per line and send to kafka
                numbytesRead = line.length();
                if (numbytesRead != 0) {   
                                    producer.send(new 
                                        KeyedMessage<String, String>(kafkaTopic,null,line));
                System.out.println(line);
                }else {
                  line = reader.readLine();
                  continue;
                }
```

EDIT: added additional code
Any help appreciated

Comment: you do not need to set the Method or Connection request properties. The connection itself will not actually happen until you call connection.getInputStream or getStatusCode or similar method to actually act on the connection.

Comment: your code looks fine. what about the url that you are requesting? Does it accept get?

Comment: You should show more code. What happens in your code after you call `getConnection`? BTW you have to remove header `Method`, there is a method for this purpose. And the header `ContentType` should read `Content-Type`. And if you no longer want to fight with the beast `HttpURLConnection`, you should consider using one of the libraries listed on [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/#background).

Comment: I inserted a second attempt to connect - connection.connect(). Is HttpURLConnection problematic? I will make the corrections about the properties and header.

Comment: Oh wait; it actually worked. Not sure if it was just the minor changes in the header properties but I can see data coming in. Perhaps the stream I was connected to was just not pushing data at the time. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I have an additional question: if I want to make a single connection that stays open and just read from the input stream then this code should work fine, correct? But for some reason I am getting the same message back.